# Does anyone know how to just remove the small groups and keep the grouped object property for dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I get a groupby object using the df.groupby(). Then I want to filter those groups of small size but keep the remained data still in a grouped structure.

Answers I founded online, such as `grouped = grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x)>2)` return a DataFrame where the data are not grouped.

Comment: You could group the filtered data no?

Answer (score 1):

Why not re-group it using your original grouping criteria?

```
df.groupby( ... ).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2).groupby( ... )
```

Comment: I see. I am just curious if there is a built in method can do this. Thanks!